# JSONArray in JSONObject, how to retrieve?

Tags: android, json, arrays

I have a JSONObject with 2 JSONArrays with JSONObjects. I'm wondering how do I access the JSONObjects in the JSONArray located in the JSONObject?(JSON inception!).

Clarify(even I get confused of writing it this)

I first get an JSONObject
This object contains 2 JSONArrays
These 2 arrays have X and Y amounts of JSONObjects.

How I reach the "Deepest" JSONObjects? How do I "unfold" the first JSONObject to get the first 2 JSONArrays?

Any hints or tricks to share?

Comment: find one good example to start here http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-parsing-web-service-response-part-1/

Answer (score 2):

Yuo could use something like this `new JSONObject(json).getJSONArray(arrayname1).getJSONObject(positionx)`.
Here `json` is the JSON response string. `arrayname1` is the name of your first array. and `poitionx` is any position fromX JSONObjects.
Similarly you could use `new JSONObject(json).getJSONArray(arrayname2).getJSONObject(positiony)` for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

> Any hints or tricks to share?

Yes, use a JSON library like [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) from Google.

Here is a reference on using it. http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example.
Suppose We have an JSONObject "Space" having two arrays: one and two.

```
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url");
                 HttpResponse  response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                 InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                 String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
                 JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result);
                 JSONObject resp= (JSONObject) json.get("response");                                  
                 JSONObject Space=resp.getJSONObject("Space");
                 JSONArray One=Space.getJSONArray("one");
                 int Length=One.length();
                 for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
                 {
                  JSONObject item = (JSONObject) items.get(j);
                   String x=item.getString("x);
                   String y=item.getString("y");
                   System.out.println("x = "+x+" , y = "+y);
                 }
```

And in the same manner you can work with second array.